# Palabra reservada new en java

Tags: java, poo

No entiendo muy bien el concepto de new ni que realiza exactamente (a pesar de que lo utilizo siempre para crear objetos)

Lo que quisiera saber es lo siguiente

Lo normal al usar esta palabra es de la siguiente manera

```
ClaseP clase = new ClaseP();
```

La cuestión empieza cuando veo estos casos:

```
ClaseP clase = new ClaseOM();
```

Vi esto alguna vez y me surgió esa pregunta. No la podía resolver porque no entendía en sí el concepto de new

Otra cuestión que surge:

```
String s[] = new String[5] ;
```

En este momento ya no invoco al constructor sino que pongo unas llaves y no entiendo porque sucede esto(tengo claro que estoy creando un arreglo)

Ahora bien, he escuchado que con la palabra new se crea el objeto en si

Pero entonces porque al crear un objeto de tipo String, int, boolean, etc... En la asignación de valor ya no se coloca el new, por lo tanto el objeto ya está siendo creado:

```
String s = "Santi";
```

Eso sería todo gracias... (la cuestión principal radica en la palabra reservada new)

Comment: ¿ Tienes claro lo que es un *puntero*, *apuntador* y/o *referencia* ?

Comment: Guarda el espacio en memoria no es asi?. Hasta esa parte sé...

Comment: ... ummmm ... va a ser *complicadillo* de explicartelo ...

Comment: @BetaM La verdad es que una buena pregunta, y no me suena de haberla visto otras veces ... pero tiene un montón de trabajo y de escribir ... igual luego si hace menos calor :-)

Comment: @Trauma Esto se de referencias: cuando se va a crear una variable se necesita del espacio en memoria, al crear la variable se guarda (en alguna parte) la raferencia de ese espacio... En C++ cuando se pone *P = &M, en el apuntador P se guarda la referencia de M. No se como se aplica esto en java, ya que hasta donde he trabajo no he utilizado apuntadores

Comment: Los apuntadores en Java se usan  _de forma implícita_ al usar cualquier instancia de una clase... uno no los escribe, pero ahí están.... quizás la simplificación haga que la vida de los desarrolladores sea más facil, pero com un background de C o C++, uno puede ver más claramente como trabajan en Java.

Comment: No uses conceptos como punteros, direcciones de memoria en Java. En Java no existe nada de eso. Lo que debes comprender es que el operador `new` devuelve una referencia (básicamente es un número..) y con esa "referencia" puedes identificar al objeto y justamente esa "referencia" la guardas en una variable para darle un uso después. Listo eso es todo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ClaseP instancia = new ClaseOM();
```

La clase `ClaseOM` es una *subclase* de `ClaseP` así que todas las instancias de `ClaseOM` son instancias de `ClaseP`.. más *no* viceversa, por ejemplo la clase ClaseOtra extiende ClaseP, entonces:

```
ClaseP otraInstancia = new ClaseOtra(); // gud
ClaseOM unOM = (ClaseOM) otraInstancia; // not gud
```

EL compilador no se va a quejar.... pero eso va a estallar en tiempo de ejecución.

A diferencia de C (y asumo que C++), los arreglos no se instancian con solo definirlos. Si uno define en C algo como:

```
int[40] arreglo;
```

Tan pronto se llega a esa línea en la ejecución, en ese momento se reservan 40 localidades de memoria para ser manejadas a través de arreglo. En Java, eso no sucede. Un arreglo es un tipo especial de Objeto que solo asegura la reserva del espacio para el apuntador:

```
int[] arreglo;
```

En ese punto solo se reserva la memoria para guardar el apuntador cuando instancies el arreglo, y es por ello que el tamaño se especifica al lllamar a new.

Los Strings son una clase especial en Java.

```
String s = "Santi";
```

En ese caso está dejando que la JVM te de la instancia de "Santi", es casi como llamar al constructor de String con new... salvo que hay detalles como que la JVM busca esa cadena en su cache. Por eso, esto funciona y nos dice que las cadenas son las mismas.

```
String s = "Algo";
String w = "Algo";
if (s == w) {
    System.out.println("Las instancias son las mismas");
}
if (w.equals(s)) {
    System.ut.println("Y el equals dice true");
}
```

Pero en este caso, las instancias son diferentes así que solo sale el mensaje del equals:

```
String s = new String("Algo");
String w = new String("Algo");
if (s == w) {
    System.out.println("Las instancias son las mismas");
}
if (w.equals(s)) {
    System.ut.println("Y el equals dice true");
}
```

Comment: @BetaM Tranquil@, no es una competencia.

Answer (score 3):

La palabra clave new basicamente crea una nueva instancia de ese Objeto, de esta manera
`ClaseP clase = new ClaseP();` sirve para crear un nuevo objeto de ClaseP y almacenarlo en clase.

En este otro caso: `ClaseP clase = new ClaseOM();` Lo que estás viendo es polimorfia, la palabra new sirve exactamente para lo mismo pero lo que te falta por saber en este caso es que la declaración de ClaseOM sería algo así: `public class ClaseOM extends ClaseP{}` dado que ClaseOM es una clase "hija" de ClaseP, se puede almacenar en una variable de ese tipo, ya que tecnicamente también es una ClaseOM.

`String s[] = new String[5] ;` En este caso, lo que estás creando es un array de objectos de clase String. Los [] sirven para indicar la cantidad de objetos que quieres crear.

Y por último, las "clases" int, boolean, float... se refieren a tipos primitivos, tipos, que no clases. Si quisieras crear una clase de "int" tendrías que hacer `Integer x = new Integer();`

Espero habértelo aclarado un poco :)

Comment: Para una explicación más técnica y en detalle, recomiendo leer la respuesta de @eftshift0
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383107/188830